# Viewing static pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
class Page extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->view('home');
    }

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
```

I want to view the pages with links as http://www.mydomain.com/page/about, http://www.mydomain.com/page/services  etc not in format http://www.mydomain.com/page/view/about and http://www.mydomain.com/page/view/services

How can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `config/routes.php` you can add a route:

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = "/page/view/$1";
```

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly

Answer (score 3):

Set a route in /config/route.php for your specific static pages.

```
$route['contact']   = 'site/page/contact';
```